# Point in time calculation

Tags: excel, scripting, sas, reporting, qlikview

I have a challenge that and unsure how to tackle it. I have some call centre data like this

```
Incident number    Received date    Closed Date
-----------------------------------------------
  111               01/01/2020      01/06/2020
  222               01/04/2020      01/09/2020
  333               01/05/2020      01/10/2020
  444               01/07/2020
```

What I want to do i point in time reporting for  each month in 2020 what was the average age of open incidents.  So for example in 2020 month  one the count will be only one as there has been one incident raised in 2020 01 and it was still open in 2020 01. By month 5 the count will be 3 as none of the incidents have closed yet, however by month 6 the count will be 2 as we now have a claim closed in month 6.  The incidents that remain open will be counted for every month after the created date until the closed date. It would have to be scripted but not sure how to tackle this. Any ideas?

Tools available: QlikView, SAS, Excel

Comment: In Excel, consider using COUNTIFS to get your desired output in another table

Comment: The answer from @Foxfire And Burns And Burns looks good but I was about to ask whether you need the average age of the incidents open in a given month as well? In the case of January, would it be the average of 1 and 31 => 16 because the incident is one day old on Jan 1st and 31 days old on Jan 31st if you count inclusively? For months where there is more than one incident open it would be more complicated.

Comment: Or would it be the average age of incidents open on the 1st of each month which would be much simpler?

Comment: @TomSharpe it would be average age at the point in time. So when reporting for Jan 2020 you want to know what was opened before then that is still open including what was closed before that date and then take that to give you an average

Comment: OK so could you say what the result of a manual calculation would be for (say) July, where you have one closed incident and three open incidents? If you take 1st July as the reference point, it might be 6 + 3 + 2 + 0 months (the last one has only just been opened) ?

Comment: So the average might be 11/4 = 2.75 months?

Comment: @TomSharpe So let take this example 

Incident number Received date Closed Date Time taken to close
111 01 January 2021 07 May 2021 126
222 01 January 2021 16 February 2021 46
333 01 January 2021 07 January 2021 6
444 01 January 2021 27 September 2021 269
555 01 January 2021  
666 01 January 2021

Comment: @TomSharpe Added it as a sperate thread for clarity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436189/point-in-time-calculation-2

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Formula to count incidents:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$5;"<="&EDATE(E3;1)-1)-COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$5;"<="&EDATE(E3;1)-1)
```

We use EDATE to get exactly 1 month ahead of current one, and minus one, so we get always the **last** day of the current month, even if it has 28, 29, 30 o 31 days.

With COUNTIF you count total incidents opened before last day of current month minus total closed incidents before last day of current month.

The value of the Month columns must be first day of each month but thanks to format, you can format the cells to **look like** just the month (but the value will be always a day!!!) so it looks more professional:

[image]

Aplying format `mmm yy` to selection make it looks better (just my opinion)