# Point in time calculation #2

Tags: excel, scripting, sas, qlikview

| Incident number | Received date | Closed Date | Time taken to close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 01 Jan 2021 | 01 Feb 2021 | 31 |
| 222 | 01 Jan 2021 | 07 Feb 2021 | 37 |
| 333 | 01 Jan 2021 |  |  |
| 444 | 01 Jan 2021 |  |  |

I wanted to calculate the  average number of days an incidents have been open at a point in time. So using the example above lets say at the end of Feb 2021 you would look at

1. Received  date has to be less then the metric date (the metric date in this case being Feb 2021)
2. Closed date has to be either greater then metric date or empty (if the closed date is empty then the calculation for time taken to close would be from the received date to the metric date)

Using the example above the first two incidents would not been included, however the last two would be and so the different between 01 Jan 2021 and 28th Feb 2021 is 58 , divide that number by 2 as that’s the number of incidents included in the calculation to give you an average of 58. Using the same example the calculation for Jan 2021 would be 31 days for each incident as no incident was closed by 31st Jan, so its (31*4) / 4. I would be repeating this for Jan – Dec 2020 and 2021

Comment: Use averageifs(), much like the other solution you have been given. A good exercise for you.

Comment: When you say repeat this for Jan 2020-Dec 2021 is that in reference to your metric date? What is the expected final output supposed to look like? What tool are you using, you have three mentioned in the tags? And most importantly, what have you tried. [ask]

Comment: So have an average calculation for points in time for Jan 2020, Feb 2020 etc, tried the countif method, however excel keeps crashing! Need to try find a smarter solution. I found first filtering on received dates for each metric point and then look at the 2nd part of the query

Answer (score 0):

The encoding of an unclosed incident with a missing value will require a case of if statement to properly compute the days open metric on a given `asof` date.

Example:

The days open average is computed for a variety of `asof` dates stored in a data set.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(2022);
  do id = 1 to 10;
    opened = '01jan2021'd + rand('integer', 60);
    closed = opened + rand('integer', 90);
    if rand('uniform') < 0.25 then call missing(closed);
    output;
  end;
  format opened closed yymmdd10.;
run;

data asof;
  do asof = '01jan2021'd to '01jun2021'd-1;
    output;
  end;
  format asof yymmdd10.;
run;

proc sql;
  create table averageDaysOpen_asof
  as
  select 
    asof
  , mean (days_open) as days_open_avg format=6.2
  , count(days_open) as id_count
  from
    ( select asof
    , opened
    , closed
    , case 
        when closed is not null and asof between opened and closed then asof-opened
        when closed is     null and asof > opened                  then asof-opened
        else .
      end as days_open
    from asof
    cross join have
    )
  group by asof
  ;
quit;
```

[image]